# Android/Google Maps: get distance of route travelled

Tags: android, google-maps

I'm looking for a way of improving accuracy of gps measurements of distance travelled (in a car).

The easiest solution would be to sum the straight-line distance between every position reading returned by the GPS. The main problem I see with that is each sequential position reading reported by the GPS can vary by a significant number of meters, so it report a stationary car as travelling around that position randomly, potentially at quite a speed. (?) One knee-jerk alternative would be to have position sampled only if the car appears to have moved at least the distance of the GPS's minimum accuracy. This is not perfect either, not least because choosing that value would be a guess. Too large and if a car needs to follow a tight weaving route of sorts, the distance travelled could be significantly under-reported. Yet another problem is handling coming and going of the gps signal and its accuracy.

So, I'd be happier with a solution that builds on Google's work. Or anyone else's, for that matter.

Is there an App I can interface with that can collect data and return a route travelled, (to the best of its ability?)

I'm just guessing now, but, since Google's navigation app can give directions, it must be pretty confident of the road a person's on, and so the route he's taking, and there must be other apps as well, to deal with this problem?

Thanks